# ft-syntax-omni is not working

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

Looks like [ft-syntax-omni](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ft-syntax-omni) has the ability to fill the omni auto completion list from syntax highlighting, but I couldn't get it to work:

In my VIMrc, I've got:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.idc set ft=idc
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.idc setlocal omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

And I'm using the syntax [highlighting file here](https://raw.github.com/CaledoniaProject/VIM-IDC/master/syntax/idc.vim), now the highlighting works fine.

But the list wasn't populated, I get nothing with `^X^O`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I didn't find a definite answer from the implementation, the fact that `:help ft-syntax-omni` speaks about

> ... knowing what keywords are part of a language.

I think it is limited to `:syntax keyword` definitions. Your `syntax/idc.vim` uses `:syntax match`, which specifies a regular expression *pattern*. To feed insert mode completion, you need concrete matches (e.g. `foobar`), not patterns (like `/f.*bar/`), so I think you either have to rewrite the syntax to define keywords, or use another means of completion, e.g. *dictionary completion* from a separate file.